# Java EE managed bean and business bean

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, javabeans

I don´t really unterstand why i should create a managed bean which is accessing the business bean.
I mean i want to create a page where a product list is displayed. Therefor i have to create an entity "product", a bean where the business logic happens (list, create,...) and a managed bean where i access the business bean. In my case in the managed bean there will be the exact same methods as in the business bean. Is that correct?

Illustration:

```
JSF calls ManagedBean.list()
ManagedBean calls BusinessBean.list()
```

Comment: Law of Demeter. Separation of concerns. Less effort if you ever need to replace JSF by something else, or want to reuse business service by something else (RESTful webservice, plain servlet, Spring MVC, etc). Also, this way it's much easier unit-testable. No need to explicitly submit a HTML page in order to test business service code. Makes just sense, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might put and run everything in one black box, but it's not recommended.
The Enterprise JavaBeans are supposed to perform actions related to the database or external resources. The managed beans are responsible of interaction with your pages (View) and with those EJB (Logic). The JSF framework respects the MVC architecture which *isolates* the layers from each others: your entites and logic layer (Model) and your pages (View).

Comment: so it is ok do it like i described it?